# How do I check whether an open port is TCP or UDP?

Tags: sockets, port

I am working on making a port scanner . I can check whether ports are open or not by trying to make a connection with the port but, how I will check the open port is udp or tcp?

Comment: Did you make a connection using UDP or TCP? You have to say which one, when you create the socket...

Comment: If you are scanning the local machine, there are platform APIs available to query the local port tables directly. But if you are trying to scan a remote machine, there is simply no way to directly determine whether a given port is using TCP or UDP. All you can do is try both and see what happens. Try to `connect()` a TCP socket to the port and see if it succeeds. Try to send UDP packets to the port and see if you get any non-ICMP (host unreachable, port unreachable, etc) replies back.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ... how I will check the open port is udp or tcp?

What you seem to have in mind is a single street where the ports are house numbers and in each house TCP and/or UDP might live. And you knock on the door and then need to figure out if UDP or TCP opened the door. But this view is wrong.

It is more like two separate streets which just have the same house numbers. There is one street for TCP and another for UDP and you decide which street to walk by choosing the type of socket. No need to check who is living in there since in the TCP street only TCP can live and in the UDP street only UDP.

A TCP socket gets created with AF_INET (or AF_INET6) and SOCK_STREAM. A UDP socket uses SOCK_DGRAM instead of SOCK_STREAM. So you know by creating the socket what you expect, i.e. which street to walk.

Apart from that UDP does not have the concept of an actual connection: while one can `connect` a UDP socket this will set the destination address on the local socket. It does not actually send any data to the peer to establish a connection like done with TCP. Thus a `connect` on a UDP socket will basically always succeed, no matter if something is expecting traffic on the destination (i.e port is "open") or not.

Answer (score 1):

A single port can have any number of services running on it, using different protocols.  Connecting only means that you connected with a specific protocol, and you'll need to check the other(s).

So, while it's probably unsatisfying as an answer, if you've been probing with TCP, you've probably never found a UDP service, and vice versa.  And if you've been probing with XTP or something similarly obscure you've probably never found an open port.

Of course, be careful.  "Connection" has different meanings under different protocols, particularly the stream-oriented protocols like TCP.  You might have "connected" in an informal sense (provoked the server to acknowledge you), but you may not be "connected" in the sense of establishing a connection where the you definitely have the server's attention.

Comment: *"A single port can have any number of services running on it, using different protocols."* - I would not describe it this way. Only TCP and UDP are protocols which have ports in the first place, i.e. ICMP has not. And this is not a single port which can support multiple protocols, these are different ports which have the same number. TCP and UDP are more like different streets where you have the same house numbers - it is not a single house where two parties (TCP and UDP) live.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich, there are hundreds of protocols out there, only a few dozen have ended up in `/etc/protocols`. But even among the "official" list, XTP, RDP (not the Microsoft one), and others aren't hard to find in the field.

Comment: True, there are a few more protocols which have ports, like SCTP. As far as I can see XTP though has no concept of a port. Still, there is no generic concept of a port and then the protocol inside. Instead some protocols have the concept of a port, others not.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich, therefore, "A single port can have any number of services running on it," because there's no accounting for every experimental protocol. But there's no reason to assume that "any number" would include any specific protocol, which is why I didn't say that.